# Force server TextChanged event from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events

I've got a asp:TextBox that is populated from a javascript function, but when this happens the server side TextChanged event is not fired, only when I change the text with my keyboard.

Is there a solution for this? Why is client/server integration so painful in asp.net?

(AutoPostBack is set to true)

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Way 1:**

```
function DoPostBack()
{
   __doPostBack("txt_sssn_dt", "TextChanged");
}
```

[Calling ASP.NET server-side events using JavaScript](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25180/Calling-ASP-NET-server-side-events-using-JavaScrip)

**Way 2:**

[Calling Server Side function from Client Side Script](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2012/01/calling-server-side-function-from.html)

**Way 3:**

one of the way to set focus lost like this

```
function texboxchange() {
        var txtBox = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox4.ClientID %>');
        var count = txtBox.value.length;
        if (count == 2) 
        {
           document.getElementById('<%= TextBox12.ClientID %>').focus();
           return true; // this will call textbox changed event.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

you can force it firing using  `__doPostBack('footxtBox','TextChanged');` in your `JS` function.

Comment: Thank you, valid answer also, I chose Pranay Rana as it's more complete, but I'll use _doPostBack. Thanks